# Attempt to Index Field '1' (a nil value) - Understanding Matrices in Lua

Tags: matrix, lua

This is a simplified version of my actual code and shows the problem I am having. I am very new to Lua and programming in general and would like to understand how Lua handles matrices.

```
grid={}
for i=1,4 do
    grid[i]={}
end
grid["1"]["1"]=0
n1=io.read()
n2=io.read()
print(grid[n1][n2])
```

Comment: Could you describe the 'problem' ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `1` is a number and `"1"` is a string. Use `grid[1][1]` instead and convert your input to a number with `tonumber()`.

```
grid={}
for i=1,4 do
    grid[i]={}
end
grid[1][1]=0
n1=tonumber(io.read())
n2=tonumber(io.read())
print(grid[n1][n2])
```